# POSTFIX Won't Start says: bind 0.0.0.0 port 25: Address already in use

Tags: linux, debian, postfix, email-server

Sorry, I've read tons of related topics but didn't get solutions for my issue.

Suddenly this morning, POSTFIX did not respond. I didn't do anything special in my server.

POSTFIX status says :

```
postfix.service - LSB: Postfix Mail Transport Agent
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/postfix)
Drop-In: /run/systemd/generator/postfix.service.d
       └─50-postfix-$mail-transport-agent.conf
Active: active (exited) since Sat 2019-02-02 13:40:22 CET; 10s ago
Process: 19382 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/postfix stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
     Process: 19398 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/postfix start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Feb 02 13:40:22 ns339072.ip-188-165-253.eu postfix[19398]: Starting Postfix Mail Transport Agent: postfix.
Feb 02 13:40:22 ns339072.ip-188-165-253.eu systemd[1]: Started LSB: Postfix Mail Transport Agent.
Feb 02 13:40:22 ns339072.ip-188-165-253.eu postfix/master[19507]: fatal: bind 0.0.0.0 port 25: Address already in use
```

says PORT 25 already in use but I can't find by whom?

sendmail is not activated on my server.

```
netstat -lnp |grep :25
```

returns nothing

postconf -n :

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
allow_percent_hack = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
config_directory = /etc/postfix
home_mailbox = Maildir/
mailbox_command = /usr/bin/procmail-wrapper -o -a $DOMAIN -d $LOGNAME
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, $mydomain
mydomain = bilp.fr
myhostname = mail.bilp.fr
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = $mydomain
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
sender_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/bcc
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/dependent
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated    reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

/etc/network/interfaces :

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo eth0 eth0:1 eth0:2 eth0:3 eth0:4 eth0:5 eth0:6 eth0:7 eth0:8 eth0:9
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet static
    address 188.165.253.141
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 188.165.253.255
    gateway 188.165.253.254

iface eth0 inet6 static
    address 2001:41d0:0002:c88d::
    netmask 64
    dns-nameservers 2001:41d0:3:163::1
    post-up sleep 5; /sbin/ip -family inet6 route add 2001:41d0:0002:c8ff:ff:ff:ff:ff dev eth0
    post-up sleep 5; /sbin/ip -family inet6 route add default via 2001:41d0:0002:c8ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    pre-down /sbin/ip -family inet6 route del default via 2001:41d0:0002:c8ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    pre-down /sbin/ip -family inet6 route del 2001:41d0:0002:c8ff:ff:ff:ff:ff dev eth0

iface eth0:1 inet static
    address 188.165.53.208
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 188.165.53.255
    network 188.165.53.0


iface eth0:2 inet static
    address 149.202.31.242
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 149.202.31.255
    network 149.202.31.0

iface eth0:3 inet static
    address 178.33.162.237
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 178.33.162.255
    network 178.33.162.0

iface eth0:4 inet static
    address 178.32.54.176
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 178.32.54.255
    network 178.32.54.0

iface eth0:5 inet static
    address 149.202.114.212
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 149.202.114.255
    network 149.202.114.0

iface eth0:6 inet static
    address 149.202.115.224
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 149.202.115.255
    network 149.202.115.0

iface eth0:7 inet static
    address 46.105.76.217
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 46.105.76.255
    network 46.105.76.0

iface eth0:8 inet static
    address 91.121.34.20
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 91.121.34.255
    network 91.121.34.0

iface eth0:9 inet static
    address 94.23.45.172
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 94.23.45.255
    network 94.23.45.0
```

ip addr :

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether 42:6a:1c:b2:03:b5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: dummy0: <BROADCAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether 92:0b:61:9e:4a:1c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: ifb0: <BROADCAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 32
link/ether ea:d2:75:2b:ec:b0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: ifb1: <BROADCAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 32
link/ether c2:c6:f1:b0:2b:72 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether a4:bf:01:00:ca:15 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 188.165.253.141/24 brd 188.165.253.255 scope global eth0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet 188.165.53.208/24 brd 188.165.53.255 scope global eth0:1
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet 149.202.31.242/24 brd 149.202.31.255 scope global eth0:2
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet 178.33.162.237/24 brd 178.33.162.255 scope global eth0:3
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet 178.32.54.176/24 brd 178.32.54.255 scope global eth0:4
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet 149.202.114.212/24 brd 149.202.114.255 scope global eth0:5
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet 149.202.115.224/24 brd 149.202.115.255 scope global eth0:6
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet 46.105.76.217/24 brd 46.105.76.255 scope global eth0:7
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet 91.121.34.20/24 brd 91.121.34.255 scope global eth0:8
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet 94.23.45.172/24 brd 94.23.45.255 scope global eth0:9
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:41d0:2:c88d::/64 scope global
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::a6bf:1ff:fe00:ca15/64 scope link
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether a4:bf:01:00:ca:16 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
8: teql0: <NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 100
link/void
9: tunl0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1
link/ipip 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
10: gre0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1476 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1
link/gre 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
11: gretap0@NONE: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1462 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
12: sit0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1
link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
13: ip6tnl0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1452 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1
link/tunnel6 :: brd ::
```

/etc/hosts:

```
# Do not remove the following line, or various programs
# that require network functionality will fail.
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
188.165.253.141         ns339072.ip-188-165-253.eu      ns339072
2001:41d0:0002:c88d::   ns339072.ip-188-165-253.eu      ns339072

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
#(added automatically by netbase upgrade)

::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

postconf -M:

```
188.165.253.141:smtp inet n -    -       -       -       smtpd -o     smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
smtp       inet  n       -       -       -       1       postscreen
smtp4      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp -o     inet_protocols=ipv4
pickup     unix  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
cleanup    unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr       unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr     unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite    unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer      unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace      unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify     unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush      unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap   unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix  -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp       unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
relay      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
showq      unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error      unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry      unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard    unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local      unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual    unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp       unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil      unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache     unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
maildrop   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=DRhu     user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
uucp       unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=Fqhu     user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=F     user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix - n       n       -       2       pipe flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user}     ${extension}
mailman    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py ${nexthop} ${user}
188.165.253.141:submission inet n - -    -       -       smtpd -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
91.121.34.20:smtp inet n -       -       -       -       smtpd -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o smtpd_tls_cert_file=/home/terrasse-bois/ssl.cert -    o smtpd_tls_key_file=/home/terrasse-bois/ssl.key
127.0.0.1:smtp inet n    -       -       -       -       smtpd -o     smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
91.121.34.20:submission inet n - -       -       -       smtpd -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o smtpd_tls_cert_file=/home/terrasse-bois/ssl.cert -o smtpd_tls_key_file=/home/terrasse-bois/ssl.key
127.0.0.1:submission inet n -    -       -       -       smtpd -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
178.33.162.237:smtp inet n -     -       -       -       smtpd -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o smtpd_tls_cert_file=/home/pergola_comoconstruir/ssl.cert -o smtpd_tls_key_file=/home/pergola_comoconstruir/ssl.key
178.33.162.237:submission inet n - -     -       -       smtpd -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o smtpd_tls_cert_file=/home/pergola_comoconstruir/ssl.cert -o smtpd_tls_key_file=/home/pergola_comoconstruir/ssl.key
178.32.54.176:smtp inet n -      -       -       -       smtpd -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o smtpd_tls_cert_file=/home/pergola.howtodiyhome/ssl.cert -o smtpd_tls_key_file=/home/pergola.howtodiyhome/ssl.key
178.32.54.176:submission inet n - -      -       -       smtpd -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o smtpd_tls_cert_file=/home/pergola.howtodiyhome/ssl.cert -o smtpd_tls_key_file=/home/pergola.howtodiyhome/ssl.key
```

netstat -ntlp as root:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8012            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1795/php-fpm.conf)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8013            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1795/php-fpm.conf)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8014            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1795/php-fpm.conf)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:110             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1522/dovecot
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2222            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1544/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8015            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1795/php-fpm.conf)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:143             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/init
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2582/perl
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8016            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1795/php-fpm.conf)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8017            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1795/php-fpm.conf)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8018            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1795/php-fpm.conf)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8019            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1795/php-fpm.conf)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8020            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1795/php-fpm.conf)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8021            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1795/php-fpm.conf)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1499/named
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8022            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1795/php-fpm.conf)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8023            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1795/php-fpm.conf)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8024            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1795/php-fpm.conf)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8025            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1795/php-fpm.conf)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1499/named
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8026            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1795/php-fpm.conf)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8027            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1795/php-fpm.conf)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8028            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1795/php-fpm.conf)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8029            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1795/php-fpm.conf)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8030            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1795/php-fpm.conf)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8031            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      944/php-fpm: pool 1
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:20000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2580/perl
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8032            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1795/php-fpm.conf)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1795/php-fpm.conf)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8033            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1795/php-fpm.conf)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1795/php-fpm.conf)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8034            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1795/php-fpm.conf)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8002            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1795/php-fpm.conf)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8003            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1795/php-fpm.conf)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8004            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1795/php-fpm.conf)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8005            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1795/php-fpm.conf)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8006            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1795/php-fpm.conf)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8007            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1795/php-fpm.conf)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10023         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1479/postgrey.pid -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8008            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1795/php-fpm.conf)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8009            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1795/php-fpm.conf)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2247/mysqld
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8010            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1795/php-fpm.conf)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8011            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1795/php-fpm.conf)
tcp6       0      0 :::110                  :::*                    LISTEN      1522/dovecot
tcp6       0      0 :::2222                 :::*                    LISTEN      1544/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::143                  :::*                    LISTEN      1/init
tcp6       0      0 :::10000                :::*                    LISTEN      2582/perl
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      2217/apache2
tcp6       0      0 ::1:53                  :::*                    LISTEN      1499/named
tcp6       0      0 ::1:953                 :::*                    LISTEN      1499/named
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      2217/apache2
```

I have tried to reboot server. No progress.

Please HELP!

Comment: Does `sudo lsof -i:25` or `telnet localhost:25` return anything?

Comment: Hi Thomas. lsof -i:25 returns NOTHING. telnet localhost:25 says: telnet: could not resolve localhost:25/telnet: Name or service not known

Comment: just fyi: the port syntax for telnet is `telnet <host> <port>`, not `telnet <host>:<port>`, so you would need to use `telnet localhost 25`.

Comment: telnet localhost 25 : telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Comment: will be much easier if the port 25 is listening :) anyway I do not come with empty hand, I found out this article (it is for redhat and unverified) could be a good start point to troubleshoot: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/45294

Comment: @AtomiX84 I ran the 1st script and it said: No sockets found that are bound but not in use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to run different TLS certificates on different IP addresses. You have configured `master.cf` to answer the `smtp` and `submission` ports for specific IPv4 addresses with different TLS certificates.

But, you have also left in the original `smtp` line which, for some reason, is set to call `postscreen`. This line is triggering the error. It can't bind to INADDR_ANY because specific IP address listeners have already been bound. That is why you get the error `Address already in use`. And the reason you don't see anything in `netstat` or `lsof` output is because Postfix quits and the addresses are unbound.

You should comment that line out of `master.cf`.

Comment: THX @Michael Hampton. POSTIX has restarted and port 25 is available. But mail server is still not working. I have opened an other thread: https://serverfault.com/questions/952105/postfix-mail-server-not-responding-connect-from-unknown