# postfix mail server not responding + connect from unknown

Tags: linux, postfix, email-server, gmail

Two days ago, my postfix failed without any actions from me. First, I had an issue with blocked port 25. Now this is now solved: [POSTFIX Won't Start says: bind 0.0.0.0 port 25: Address already in use](https://serverfault.com/questions/952013/postfix-wont-start-says-bind-0-0-0-0-port-25-address-already-in-use)

But my SMTP mail server `mail.bilp.fr` is still not available.

When I test the server with https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=smtp%3amail.bilp.fr&run=toolpage#
it goes to a `Failed to connect`

Also, my GMAIL can't send thru my server.

`service postfix status`:

```
postfix.service - LSB: Postfix Mail Transport Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/postfix)
  Drop-In: /run/systemd/generator/postfix.service.d
       └─50-postfix-$mail-transport-agent.conf
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2019-02-03 10:36:04 CET; 9min ago
  Process: 2438 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/postfix start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/postfix.service
           ├─ 2569 /usr/lib/postfix/master
           ├─ 2570 pickup -l -t unix -u -c
           ├─ 2571 qmgr -l -t unix -u
           ├─ 8581 tlsmgr -l -t unix -u -c
           ├─ 8582 anvil -l -t unix -u -c
           ├─10426 smtpd -n 188.165.253.141:smtp -t inet -u -c -o stress= -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
           ├─10427 proxymap -t unix -u
           ├─10550 cleanup -z -t unix -u -c
           ├─10551 trivial-rewrite -n rewrite -t unix -u -c
           └─10552 local -t unix

Feb 03 10:45:02 ns339072.ip-188-165-253.eu postfix/pickup[2570]: D3349BFD0F: uid=33 from=<www-data>
Feb 03 10:45:02 ns339072.ip-188-165-253.eu postfix/cleanup[10550]: D3349BFD0F: message-id=<20190203094502.D3349BFD0F@mail.bilp.fr>
Feb 03 10:45:02 ns339072.ip-188-165-253.eu postfix/qmgr[2571]: D3349BFD0F: from=<www-data@bilp.fr>, size=863, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb 03 10:45:02 ns339072.ip-188-165-253.eu postfix/trivial-rewrite[10551]: warning: do not list domain bilp.fr in BOTH mydestination and virtual_alias_domains
Feb 03 10:45:03 ns339072.ip-188-165-253.eu postfix/local[10552]: D3349BFD0F: to=<www-data@bilp.fr>, orig_to=<www-data>, relay=local, delay=0.65, delays=0.01/0/0/0.64, dsn=2.0.... $LOGNAME)
Feb 03 10:45:03 ns339072.ip-188-165-253.eu postfix/qmgr[2571]: D3349BFD0F: removed
Feb 03 10:45:28 ns339072.ip-188-165-253.eu postfix/smtpd[10426]: connect from unknown[185.234.218.38]
Feb 03 10:45:31 ns339072.ip-188-165-253.eu postfix/smtpd[10426]: warning: unknown[185.234.218.38]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
Feb 03 10:45:31 ns339072.ip-188-165-253.eu postfix/smtpd[10426]: lost connection after AUTH from unknown[185.234.218.38]
Feb 03 10:45:31 ns339072.ip-188-165-253.eu postfix/smtpd[10426]: disconnect from unknown[185.234.218.38]
```

I use GMAIL with alias accounts. So GMAIL tries to connect to my `mail.bilp.fr` and I think that those `connect from unknown[185.234.218.38]`are the GMAIL attempts to connect to my server?

But I don't see why others failed to connect to `mail.bilp.fr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah! I found the reason: some lines were missing in `/etc/postfix/master.cf`

I had to add:

```
149.202.114.212:smtp    inet    n   -   -   -   -   smtpd -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o smtpd_tls_cert_file=/home/bilp/ssl.cert -o smtpd_tls_key_file=/home/bilp/ssl.key
149.202.114.212:submission  inet    n   -   -   -   -   smtpd -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o smtpd_tls_cert_file=/home/bilp/ssl.cert -o smtpd_tls_key_file=/home/bilp/ssl.key
```

The point is: this server had been installed 6 months ago, and POSTFIX worked fine until then. I cannot understand how POSTFIX could work without those 2 lines?

Comment: "I cannot understand how POSTFIX could work without those 2 lines?" Probably you have a problem in your local network configuration and postfix bound on the wrong network interface